# How to "sleep" computer while keeping internet connection alive

Tags: wireless, networking, power-management

I am currently using my laptop to share my internet connection with my desktop. It works great (my belkin micro-n adapter quit on me) for now, but the laptop is so hot, just sitting there burning energy. I would like to shut it down to it's lowest powered state while keeping the connection alive. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use router? There is no way to make laptop sleep while processing network requests, because they involve CPU. You'd better look for a way to make it cool through cleaning. I also think this question is off-topic here.

Comment: A router is by far the easiest solution.  It means you don't have to rely on the laptop being on all the time.  As Danatela says if the computer is in sleep mode the processor isn't running so it wont be possible to share internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't power down your Laptop in this case.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, this task cannot be done without an operating system (on normal pcs/laptops) and therefore involve your CPU. The only thing you can power down is your screen, but that will not make your Laptop significantly cooler. Except you somehow deactivate your graphics card which you should not do if you do not know linux as good as your own room. Also it's not assured this will solve your problem.

So really, there is no mode or option that will save power in such significant values. If you still want to try, there are several questions on askubuntu about power saving. Just try the search on the top (on the right side). Those can extend battery life and maybe help a little. I can recommend "Jupiter" to do this as it's really user friendly. But do not expect too much.

If this is the only thing your laptop is doing, it's a bit strange it's getting hot. Check whether your laptop fans are running (you'll find help on the fans here on askubuntu, just try the search bar). Also you could look in the system monitor what is causing your CPU to get busy/hot.

## Long term solution: a router or wlan access point

Such devices are specialized to this activity and do not consume as much energy as a laptop. They can run 24/7 without problems. This is also a very easy and relatively cheap solution.